# Purpose of _LINUX_EXPORT_H macro

Tags: linux, kernel, c

What is the purpose of defining _LINUX_EXPORT_H in include/linux/export.h? It seems to be defined in this file and never referenced anywhere else. Is it redundant?

Link: [_LINUX_EXPORT_H in torvalds/linux on github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=_LINUX_EXPORT_H&unscoped_q=_LINUX_EXPORT_H)

Comment: Are you asking about the purpose of [include guards](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/21638/idempotence)?

Comment: It appears that the questioner is asking for the purpose of that macro _not knowing that it is an include guard_.

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully at the file, it starts and ends with these lines:

```
#ifndef _LINUX_EXPORT_H
#define _LINUX_EXPORT_H
...
#endif /* _LINUX_EXPORT_H */
```

These lines mean that if the file is included twice (either through a mistake or through including another file that includes this file) then the *second* time around the value is defined, and so the whole file is effectively skipped.

These are commonly known as "header guards" or "[include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)" and you'll note that many of the standard include files use this pattern; e.g `pwd.h` has

```
#ifndef _PWD_H
#define _PWD_H  1
```